# Form handler submit don't work

Tags: 7, forms

I have a submission handler for my custom form that doesn't work. I tried many solutions, but nothing works.

#### My_Custom.module

```
 [...]
function tournament_menu() {
    $items['tournament/newteam'] = array(
        'title' => 'Créer une nouvelle équipe',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
        'page arguments' => array('form_newteam'),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'file' => 'form_tournament.inc',
    );    
}
 [...]
```

#### form_tournament.inc

```
function form_newteam ($form, &$form_state) {

 [...]
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Créer',
    );
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'form_newteam_submit';

    return $form;
}

function form_newteam_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    //Validation logic
}

function form_newteam_submit($form, &$form_state) {

    drupal_set_message("Bla bla submit !");

}
```

My validation function works.

I try all this code In `form_newteam()` function.

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'form_newteam_submit';
$form['#submit'][] = 'form_newteam_submit';
$form['#submit'] = array('form_newteam_submit');
$form['submit'] = array(
 '#type' => 'submit',
 '#value' => 'Créer',
 '#submit' => array('form_newteam_submit'),
); 


$form['submit'] = array(
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => 'Créer',
  '#submit' => 'form_newteam_submit',
);
```

Comment: There is many `form_newteam_submit` reference in your code. I hope that you are trying them one by one, not all together.

Comment: Have you cleared cache?

Answer (score 1):

Go back and scrutinize your validation function. The code you are showing here actually works, so the problem is something you did not include in your sample.

For the reference, the working implementation over here is:

```
function form_newteam ($form, &$form_state) {
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => 'Créer',
    );

    return $form;
}

function form_newteam_validate($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message("valid");
}

function form_newteam_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    drupal_set_message("submit");
}
```

Please note that your function names do not conform to the drupal coding standards. [Function names must be prefixed with the module name](https://drupal.org/coding-standards#naming). Therefore you should name your functions like this: `tournament_newteam` or `tournament_newteam_form`. If those are administrative forms, stick them into `tournament.admin.inc` otherwise place them into `tournament.pages.inc`.

Comment: I try to set the minimal code but, `drupal_set_message()` don't work in my valid and submit function now.

Comment: I recommend to start over and install drupal again, then build up your custom module step by step in the clean environment. I actually tested the code I submitted. The form API is supposed to work like this.

Comment: Yep, I try with a clean install of drupal and my module work correctly. thank !

Answer (score -1):

try

```
function form_newteam_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id = 'form_id') {

    drupal_set_message(t('Bla bla submit !'), 'status');

}
```

Comment: You've copied the function signature for `hook_form_alter()` there - that's not related to the signature of the submit function, two separate things altogther

Comment: Clive, that is incorrect. I have copied this from my own module and it does work. If the answer is incorrect to your knowledge please state that but you should not be making assumptions.

Comment: I'm not making assumptions - if you've copied the above from your custom code, then it has _originally_ been copied from the signature for `hook_form_alter()` or `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` (look them up, you'll see straight away). Either way, it's not correct for the signature of a submit handler. `$form` should not be passed by reference, and there's no third parameter. In your case it works by luck, not by design

Comment: @sly, you have set third argument as default arguments, so may be your code is working. But, clive is right, your code example is signature of `hook_form_alter`, not for `hook_form_submit`.